# Achieving Liskov-compliant contravariance in method arguments in C#

Tags: c#, object-oriented, solid, liskov-substitution

Trying to practice LSP, the following is not really clear to me:

> Liskov requirements (some)
>     -There must be contravariance of the method
>   arguments in the subtype.
>    – There must be covariance of the return
>   types in the subtype.

Also the method in a subclass could be declared with a parameter type that is more generic than in the base class, is that right?
But as far as I know, that does not work, as I tried in C#:

```
class A
{
    public virtual void Test(Cat a)
    { }

}

class B : A
{
    public override void Test(Animal a)  //shouldn't this work to be Liskov compliant?
    {

    }
}

class Animal
{ }

class Cat : Animal
{ }
```

As, to my knowledge, CLR does not support covariance except for delegates and generics, how can we implement truly LSP compliant code if this cannot be met?

Comment: Are you referring to [this article](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2255313&seqNum=3)? If so, then note that the article is talking specifically about C# generics (about what's required for generics to be LSP compliant).

Comment: @FilipMilovanović No, I have read materials relating to LSP, not language specific. All of the mention that these contra and covariance rules must apply in orded to be LSP compliant. But I cannot see how to do that in C#.

Comment: @EzoelaVacca, as the article explains, C# classes are invariant, unless generics are used. And generic variance can only be defined via interfaces. So if you want to be a LSP purist, you cannot use inheritance in C# as it doesn't support some of the requirements of LSP compliance.

Comment: I see. LSP is more general than that; the definition doesn't say anything about variance specifically. The rules you mention are inferred for type systems and language constructs that do support variance. In C#, you have to use delegates or generics to see this (covariance and contravariance are enforced by the compiler).

Comment: I am wondering, whether requesting exactly the same type (as we do in C#) would be considered LSP compliant. We are certainly not narrowing the type, just ensuring it is the same.

Comment: "you cannot use inheritance in C# as it doesn't support some of the requirements of LSP compliance" 
Or, rather, you can, but it's you who has to make sure your types adhere to LSP.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović But I think I can never achieve what is mentioned in the example. I have read that those rules are derived from class generalization principle and as such are inferred from LSP definition.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović I am thinking, isn't this implicitly supported in .NET? I mean, when I define a return type Animal, I am allowed to return Cat or Dog. At the same time, when a method accepts a parameter of type Dog, I can pass an object of Animal type.

Comment: @EzoelaVacca If your method declares the parameter as Dog, then you can't pass a Cat (an animal) which means if cannot be a substitute for a method that accepts (any) Animal.

Comment: @JimmyJames By Animal I mean the supertype of Dog. So it should comply to LSP.

Comment: @EzoelaVacca I'm a little confused.  Your example shows the subclass method declared as taking Animal but your comment seems to suggest something else.  Are you saying you want to pass an object declared to be of type Animal to a method that is declared to take Dog?  If so, that doesn't work.

Comment: @DavidArno As I have just learned, actually I can be LSP purist in C#, contravariance rules hold if the same type is used as it is type safe, thanks to types reflexion. You just must not use less or more derived types where LSP forbids it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a widespread misunderstanding of subtyping rules. Indeed, in C# you can write a code that is fully LSP compliant, because:

> Subtyping rule for function types: the argument types in the signature
>   must be **at least** as general as the actual arguments, and the return
>   type must be **at least** as specific as the actual return type.

So your code will be type safe with respect to variance as your types will be the same, satisfying the condition of function subtyping. In addition, a type A is also a subtype of itself, the relation is reflexive.

Liskov extends the subtyping rules by additional behavioral rules.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50325687.  Notice how this code sets the "User Agent" request header.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, C# is *more conservative* than the hypothetical, with respect to the declared type.

Because all overrides of `Test` *must* accept `Cat`s, they can't break the LSP this way.

You *can* however break it very easily with *behaviour*

```
class Tabby : Cat {}

class C : A
{
    public override void Test(Cat a)
    {
        if (!a is Tabby) { throw new Exception("Breaking Old Code"); }
    }
}
```